# Boost ASIO scatter-gather I/O causes mysterious memory errors

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'd like to send multiple strings through TCP without combining them into one big string first, and as I understand ASIO's scatter-gather I/O interface can do this. However, I must be doing something wrong because my implementation keeps running into memory errors. The snippet below (compilable and runnable) returns a garbled string when I `telnet localhost 11211`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

int main() {
    io_service service;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 11211));
    tcp::socket sock(service);
    acceptor.accept(sock);
    if (!acceptor.is_open()) return 1;
    string s = "this is a really long string";
    vector<const_buffer> vec;
    vec.push_back(buffer(s));
    write(sock, buffer(vec));
}
```

However, it works fine when I do `write(sock, buffer("this is a really long string"))`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Checking the `buffer` reference for [scatter-gather I/O](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html#boost_asio.reference.buffer.buffers_and_scatter_gather_i_o) the example they use have a vector of ASIO buffers, not a vector of data. Perhaps you can try that?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I did try that earlier. Example has been updated to use that method, and still fails in the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last line should be:

```
write(sock, vec);
```

Otherwise it's not "scatter-gather", because `buffer` free function always returns `mutable_buffers_1`, i.e. a *single* buffer. In your case the following `buffer` overload gets called:

```
template <typename PodType, typename Allocator>
inline mutable_buffers_1 buffer(std::vector<PodType, Allocator>& data)
{
  return mutable_buffers_1(mutable_buffer(data.size() ? &data[0] : 0, data.size() * sizeof(PodType)));
}
```

Since your vector is not a "vector of POD", it's treated incorrectly.

Comment: I assumed that `buffer` was idempotent, but I guess it isn't a copy constructor and so shouldn't be expected to have that behavior. Thank you so much!

Comment: @int3 IMHO, such a code shouldn't compile at all. I'll submit the relevant patch to ASIO.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass buffer to write in this case.
If you rewrite last string of your example as

```
write(sock, vec);
```

the problem most likely will be solved.